# web.config with net Core 3.1 trouble with publish

Tags: web-config, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-3.1

I have some trouble while publish the custom web.config I created in my application which I developed using .net Core 3.1.
I use Visual Studio 2019.

My web.config (which it work as I want if I manually update it in the server)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration >
    <system.webServer >
        <handlers>
            <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\myapplication.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false"
          stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
    <location path="images">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
        <system.webServer>
            <security>
                <authentication>
                    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
                </authentication>
            </security>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

the structure in my project is

```
web.config
 |
 |--- web.Debug.config
 |--- web.Release.config
```

web.Release.config has "Content" as "Build Action" and "Copy If Newer" as "Copy to output directory"
web.config contains only

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration >
</configuration>
```

I tried to use web.config file transformation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations

but it end up in a mess. I put "xdt:Transform="Insert"" in both tag "system.webServer" and "location". The system add both *twice* in the created web.config (on the server) and leave the default tag location.

Can you help me?